# Can't parse JSON array with JSONDecoder in Swift 4

Tags: swift

I have a JSON array I need to parse and I choose to use JSONDecoder to parse it.

JSON array looks like this:

```
[{"Id":0,"Key":"key0","Name":"name0","Title":"title0"},{"Id":1,"Key":"key1","Name":"name1","Title":"title1"},{"Id":2,"Key":"key2","Name":"name2","Title":"title2"}]
```

The problem is, JSONDecoder creates the array, but all the fields are empty in the object. What is the problem here?

Here is my playground file. You can see all fields are empty after parse:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import Foundation

class Result: Codable{
    let title: String = ""
    let id: Int = 0
    let key: String = ""
    let name: String = ""

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case title = "Title"
        case id = "Id"
        case key = "Key"
        case name = "Name"
    }
}

let data = "[{\"Id\":0,\"Key\":\"key0\",\"Name\":\"name0\",\"Title\":\"title0\"},{\"Id\":1,\"Key\":\"key1\",\"Name\":\"name1\",\"Title\":\"title1\"},{\"Id\":2,\"Key\":\"key2\",\"Name\":\"name2\",\"Title\":\"title2\"}]".data(using: .utf8)!


let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do{
    let results = try decoder.decode([Result].self, from: data)
    print("Result count: \(results.count)")
    for result in results{
        print("Name: \(result.name)")
    }
}catch let exception{
    print(exception.localizedDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the initial values for the constant properties

```
class Result: Codable{
    let title: String
    let id: Int
    let key: String
    let name: String

    // ...
}
```

(or make the properties *variable*).  Initialized constant
properties can not be set by the JSON decoder.